# StackExchange.Redis subscription recovery

Tags: publish-subscribe, stackexchange.redis

I am using StackExchange.Redis 1.0.331 (NuGet) and can't get it to work as expected per docs

> Another common use of redis is as a pub/sub message distribution tool;
>   this too is simple, and in the event of connection failure, the 
>   ConnectionMultiplexer  will handle all the details of re-subscribing
>   to the requested channels.

Test case

```
// Starting server: redis-server.exe --port 27017 --maxmemory 5mb

using (var con = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("127.0.0.1:27017")) {

    var sub = con.GetSubscriber();

    sub.Subscribe("test", (c, v) => {
        Console.WriteLine("Got notification: " + (string)v);
    });

    sub.Publish("test", "This one gets caught");

    // Restarting server.
    Console.ReadKey();

    sub.Publish("test", "This one does not");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yikes; yes, this is not good; it looks like we're getting a new `ServerEndPoint` for some reason; subscriptions are held at the `ServerEndPoint` level, so I'm not sure why... looking. Edit: hah; turns out an email I received last night contained a diff to address this... testing locally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yikes; a nasty bug crept in - spinning up a new `ServerEndPoint` incorrectly (subscriptions are held against `ServerEndPoint`, so this is: bad). Interesting timing, but somebody else independently sent me a patch for this last night (although I didn't know the two reports were related until I investigated) - this has been [merged and committed](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/commit/ecb9e3fef95e4cd853a517bbca3c053a1375cbc7), and will hopefully go to NuGet later today.

Comment: Fresh build successfully recovers subscriptions, thanks.

Comment: @poopysprint anything 1.0.333+ should be ok